# Is Maven 1.0.2 compatible with Java 5?

Tags: java, compatibility, maven

I'm working on an upgrade project and build management is done in Maven 1.0.2. Java version will change to J2SE 5.

Please include in your answer if you have first hand experience on that particular combination (Maven 1.0.2 and J2SE 5)

Thanks
hdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure the compiler settings for 1.5 (the `project.properties` would be the appropriate location):

```
#compiler settings
maven.compile.source=1.5
maven.compile.target=1.5
```

I've done this in the past, it just works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if Maven 1.0.2 works with j2se 5 or not, but I would be surprised if it didn't. However, Maven 1.0.2 is an *old* version of Maven (Maven 1.1-RC1 is the last stable release of the 1.X branch I think) and I would strongly consider moving to Maven 2.

Initial migration from Maven 1 to Maven 2 might be painful depending on how complicated the project is, but I've found Maven 2 to be worth the the trouble overall.