# Maven 1.0 Missing Dependency

Tags: java, maven, jira, dependency-management

I'm trying to setup a development environment for developing [Atlassian Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) 3.13 plug-ins.  The process is described on Atlassian's website, [here](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA03x/JIRA+Plugin+Development+Kit).  Unfortunately, Jira 3.13 is a bit out of date and as such the documentation is also out of date.  Upgrading is not currently an option.

I'm stuck on Step #3: I need to build and install the Atlassian IDEA-Maven Plugin.  I've got Maven set up, but trying to built the Atlassian plug-in results in:

```
$ maven install:install-file ~/.maven/repository/jing/jars/jing-20030619.jar
 __  __
|  \/  |__ _Apache__ ___
| |\/| / _` \ V / -_) ' \  ~ intelligent projects ~
|_|  |_\__,_|\_/\___|_||_|  v. 1.0

Plugin 'maven-deploy-plugin' in project 'Atlassian IDEA Plug-in' is not available
Attempting to download jing-20030619.jar.
WARNING: Failed to download jing-20030619.jar.

BUILD FAILED
File...... /home/mitch/.maven/cache/maven-plugin-plugin-1.5.1/plugin.jelly
Element... attainGoal
Line...... 55
Column.... 34
The build cannot continue because of the following unsatisfied dependency:

jing-20030619.jar

Total time: 1 seconds
Finished at: Wed Apr 06 16:43:34 MDT 2011
```

I was able to find the missing JAR with a quick Google search, and then by looking for some of the other dependencies that Maven had already installed, I determined that it kept the JARs locally in `~/.maven/repository/`.  Based on the structure of the subdirectories in that directory, I put the `jing-20030619.jar` in `~/.maven/repository/jing/jars/jing-20030619.jar`, hoping that Maven would look for it there.  However, Maven still can't find the JAR.  How do I tell it where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm used to work with maven 2, but had to make a build with maven 1 and had the same problem as you, with the same jar even!

Here's what I did:

1) Found the missing jar here: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/thaiopensource/jing/20030619/ and downloaded it + the pom file.

2) Change the name of **jing-20030619.pom** to **project.xml** (to comply with Maven1.x) and changed the tag **version** to **currentVersion**. Save.

3) Create a new file next to the ing-20030619.jar and project.xml named **maven.xml**.

4) Open the maven.xml file and add this content (you can specify other goal name if you want):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns:artifact="artifact">
  <goal name="teste">
    <artifact:install artifact="jing-20030619.jar" type="jar" project="${pom}" />
  </goal>  
</project>
```

5) Run maven:

```
C:\whatever\path\maven-1.0.2\bin\maven teste
```

6) Check your repository folder to see if it went OK.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  That finally did it.  I also had to change the compiler source and target settings to get the compilation to succeed, which I found instructions on how to do here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465145/is-maven-1-0-2-compatible-with-java-5

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Artifact plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/artifact/tags.html), especially the `artifact:install`goal.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use it?  maven artifact:install jing-20030619.jar just complains that 'Goal "artifact:install" does not exist in this project.'  I've looked for documentation on how to use it, but have not found any as of yet.

Comment: Official documentation was linked already ('Artifact plugin'). This is the link once more: http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/artifact/tags.html#artifact:install

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favour and upgrade to Maven 3. You will not find anybody still using Maven 1. It is long dead.

Comment: Unfortunately newer versions of Maven do not seem to be compatible with the development kit that I have to use.

Comment: What sort of age old tool are you using? Please talk to your management or whatever that using this old stuff will cost you a LOT of wasted effort and money. Let me say it again. NOBODY is maintaining Maven 1. Maven 2 gets barely much since Maven 3 replaced it as drop in compatible.